# Successor of 6 is 7 or 9?

Tags: data-structures, binary-trees

What is the successor of 6 in this tree: 7 or 9?

[image]

Comment: Hello! What have you tried? What resources have you consulted, to find how they define successor? What definition of "successor" are you using?  If your question is only one short sentence, that's often a sign that you might need to flesh out your question before posting it.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 3):

There are [many ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) to traverse a tree, and what is the 'successor' of 6 depends entirely on how you are traversing the tree. To illustrate this, here's the answer for some common traversal methods:

**Pre-order traversal**: 3.
**In-order traversal**: 9.
**Post-order traversal**: 17.
**Level-order left-to-right**: 18.
**Lever-order right-to-left**: 20.

And for completeness, you can get 7 as a successor of 6 through **reverse pre-order**.